# Generate random value by condition

Tags: php

I've an array:

```
$themes = ['class-A', 'class-B','class-C','class-D','class-E','class-F']
```

And I have the following condition:
I need to generate 12 classes out of that where:

1. class-A will occur exactly once or none.
2. class-B will occur either 3 or 6 times.
3. class-C or class-D has no limit, can occur as many times.
4. Class-E  will occur exactly twice or none.
5. class-F will occur exactly once or none.

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible implementation

```
<?php

$classAPossibleOccuences = [0,1];
$classARandomChosenOccurence = $classAPossibleOccuences[array_rand($classAPossibleOccuences)];

$classBPossibleOccuences = [3,6];
$classBRandomChosenOccurence = $classBPossibleOccuences[array_rand($classBPossibleOccuences)];


$classEPossibleOccuences = [0,2];
$classERandomChosenOccurence = $classEPossibleOccuences[array_rand($classEPossibleOccuences)];


$classFPossibleOccuences = [0,1];
$classFRandomChosenOccurence = $classFPossibleOccuences[array_rand($classFPossibleOccuences)];


$generatedRandomClassesArr = [];

if($classARandomChosenOccurence) {
  $generatedRandomClassesArr[] = 'class-A';
}

if($classFRandomChosenOccurence) {
  $generatedRandomClassesArr[] = 'class-F';
}

for($i = 0; $i < $classBRandomChosenOccurence; $i++) {
  $generatedRandomClassesArr[] = 'class-B';
}

if($classERandomChosenOccurence) {
  for($i = 0; $i < $classERandomChosenOccurence; $i++) {
    $generatedRandomClassesArr[] = 'class-E';
  }
}

while(sizeof($generatedRandomClassesArr) < 12) {
  $randomCOrD = ['C','D'];
  $randomClass = $randomCOrD[array_rand($randomCOrD)];
  $generatedRandomClassesArr[] = 'class-' . $randomClass;
}

//randomize array elements
shuffle($generatedRandomClassesArr);

highlight_string("<?php\n\$generatedRandomClassesArr =\n" . var_export($generatedRandomClassesArr, true) . ";\n?>");

echo '<br><br>';

highlight_string("<?php\n\$countValues =\n" . var_export(array_count_values($generatedRandomClassesArr), true) . ";\n?>");


?>
```

Check working [demo](https://repl.it/@FMOUSSI/EdiblePlaintiveRotation)

Comment: The question looks like a school assignment to me. You could just give hints instead of functional code. :)

Comment: Well, we were students too

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a working Demo here that must satisfy all of your rules

```
<?php

$randomClassesArr = [];

while (sizeof($randomClassesArr) <= 12) {
  $letter = chr(rand(65,70));
  $classLetter = 'class-' . $letter;

  if($letter === 'A' || $letter === 'F') {
    if(!in_array($classLetter, $randomClassesArr)) {
      $randomClassesArr[] = $classLetter;
    } 
  } elseif($letter === 'B') {
    $occurences = array_count_values($randomClassesArr);
    $classBOccurence = $occurences[$classLetter] ?? 0;

    if($classBOccurence !== 3) {
      $randomClassesArr[] = $classLetter;
    }

  } elseif($letter === 'E') {
    $occurences = array_count_values($randomClassesArr);
    $classEOccurence = $occurences[$classLetter] ?? 0;

    if($classEOccurence !== 2) {
      $randomClassesArr[] = $classLetter;
    }
  } else {
    $randomClassesArr[] = $classLetter;
  }
}

highlight_string("<?php\n\$randomClassesArr =\n" . var_export($randomClassesArr, true) . ";\n?>");

echo '<br><br>';

highlight_string("<?php\n\$countValues =\n" . var_export(array_count_values($randomClassesArr), true) . ";\n?>");

?>
```

Check [working demo here](https://repl.it/@FMOUSSI/PossibleBlankExabyte) and feel free to edit on top of it.

Comment: Check my 2nd answer below, if it doesn't help you either consider Editing you original post , cause as it's written in the comments it's not readable